# I need help to disable shadowbox from resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

This overlay seems to be the only overlay plugin that works within my schools wonky template... but the problem is that when the browser is resized the shadowbox resizes too, clipping the contents inside. I want it so the box stats fixed and if the browser does get smaller the browser will have scrollbars.

I know it's been modified before, but i dont know where to start. I cant even find an unminified version of the .js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was having this exact same issue - I found that you can force it to the height you want by putting this in the shadowbox.css file:

```
#sb-wrapper { height:560px !important; }
#sb-wrapper-inner { height:560px !important; }
```

And in your HTML markup, make sure you define the height and width in the rel attribute of the a tag:

```
<a href="somelink.php" rel="shadowbox;width=600;height=560;">Your Link</a>
```

I don't know where to start either with the JavaScript file - CSS it is.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `K.onWindowResize` function in the last lines of the `shadowbox.js` script and modify it as follows:

```
K.onWindowResize=function(){
if(!doWindowResize){return}setSize();
var player=S.player, dims=setDimensions(player.height,player.width);

//edited by gabriel esquivel 11/15/10
//adjustWidth(dims.width,dims.left);
//adjustHeight(dims.innerHeight,dims.top);
animate(wrapper,"top",dims.top,0);
animate(wrapper,"left",dims.left,0);

if(player.onWindowResize){player.onWindowResize()}};
```

Comment: Nice answer. I just left in the adjustWidth and adjustHeight calls as well and just always set the width and height in those functions. Otherwise, it wouldn't resize to the correct dimensions if it's too small to fit when you first open it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the code found at http://www.shadowbox-js.com/, if you want the images to always be of a certain size (let's say a height of 600px for the purpose of this example), adding the following to your CSS should do it:

```
#sb-wrapper-inner { height:600px !important; }
```

If there's not a static height you can force them to, it's more difficult than I can figure out on my coffee break.

Comment: Hey thanks. but this doesnt work. If you test out the examples the "box" will resize and clip whatever is inside the box. I just want it fixed.

Comment: Can you look into this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in the init

```
Shadowbox.init({
    viewportPadding:-1000
});
```

Then the pading never gets to negative and so does't resize.